# Generating cross table and mid table arrows

Tags: tables, arrows, sidebyside

[image]

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
        \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
            \caption{}
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|}
                \hline
                D & 1 & 0 & 1 & D & 1 & 1 \\
                \hline              
            \end{tabular}\vspace{0.8 cm}            
            \begin{tabular}{|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|}
               \hline
               D & 1 & 0 & 1 & D & 1 & 1 \\
               \hline
            \end{tabular}       
        \end{minipage}\vspace{-1.5cm}
    $\Rightarrow$
        \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \caption{}
            \begin{tabular}{|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|}
                \hline
                D & 1 & 0 & 1 & D & 1 & 1 \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}\vspace{0.8 cm}
        \begin{tabular}{|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|}
            \hline
            D & 1 & 0 & 1 & D & 1 & 1 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}       
        \end{minipage}    
    \end{table}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can draw the arrows with the help of tikzpicture environment with tikz node.

Here is the code..

```
\documentclass[margin=1in]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary[arrows, decorations.pathmorphing, backgrounds, positioning, fit, petri, calc]

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0pt,
        bluebox/.style={draw, fill=cyan!50, text width=0.5cm, inner sep=0.1cm, align=center},
        box/.style={draw,  text width=0.5cm, inner sep=0.1cm, align=center}]
        
        \begin{scope}
            \node[bluebox] (b7) {0};
            \node[bluebox] (b6) [right=of b7] {1};
            \node[bluebox] (b5) [right=of b6] {0};
            \node[bluebox] (b4) [right=of b5] {1};
            \node[bluebox] (b3) [right=of b4] {0};
            \node[bluebox] (b2) [right=of b3] {1};
            \node[bluebox] (b1) [right=of b2] {1};
            
            
            \node[box, yshift=-1.25cm] (a7) {1};
            \node[box] (a6) [right=of a7] {1};
            \node[box] (a5) [right=of a6] {1};
            \node[box] (a4) [right=of a5] {0};
            \node[box] (a3) [right=of a4] {0};
            \node[box] (a2) [right=of a3] {1};
            \node[box] (a1) [right=of a2] {0};
            
            \draw[->, very thick] ($(a6.south east) + (0,-0.25cm)$) node[yshift=2.5cm] {crossover point} node[yshift=-0.15cm] {Parent chromosomes} -- ($(b6.north east) + (0,0.25cm)$);
            
            
            
        \end{scope}
        
        \node[draw, single arrow,
        minimum height=30mm, minimum width=20mm,
        single arrow head extend=2mm,
        anchor=west, rounded corners=2pt, right of=b1, xshift=2.25cm, yshift=-0.75cm] (arrow)  {};
        
        
        \node [above=of arrow, yshift=1.5cm]{One Point Crossover};
        


        
        \begin{scope}[xshift=9cm]
            \node[bluebox] (b7) {0};
            \node[bluebox] (b6) [right=of b7] {1};
            \node[box] (b5) [right=of b6] {1};
            \node[box] (b4) [right=of b5] {0};
            \node[box] (b3) [right=of b4] {0};
            \node[box] (b2) [right=of b3] {1};
            \node[box] (b1) [right=of b2] {0};
            
            
            \node[box, yshift=-1.25cm] (a7) {1};
            \node[box] (a6) [right=of a7] {1};
            \node[bluebox] (a5) [right=of a6] {0};
            \node[bluebox] (a4) [right=of a5] {1};
            \node[bluebox] (a3) [right=of a4] {0};
            \node[bluebox] (a2) [right=of a3] {1};
            \node[bluebox] (a1) [right=of a2] {1};
            
            \node [below of=a4, yshift=-0.75cm] {Offspring chromosomes};
            
        \end{scope}     
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: THe output is shown as]

Answer (score 1):

A `pstricks` solution: I inserted 2 `\rnode`s, then connected them with a node connection. For the bigarrow, I loaded `pst-arrow` and used `\psBigArrow` to connect an empty node (`\pnode`) placed at the end of the first minipage and another placed at the beginning of the second minipage.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
 \usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array, caption}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pst-node, pst-arrow}
\colorlet{mygrey}{Gainsboro!50!Lavender}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[!htb]
    \sffamily\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
    \begin{minipage}{.35\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|*{7}{wc{0.3cm}|}}
        \multicolumn{7}{l}{\hskip 1.5em\rnode[bl]{C}{Crossover point}} \\[1.5ex]
            \hline
   \rowcolor{mygrey} D & 1 & 0 & 1 & D & 1 & 1 \\
            \hline
    \noalign{\vspace{0.4cm}}
           \hline
           D & 1 & 0 & 1 & D & 1 & 1 \\
           \hline
    \noalign{\vskip 1.5ex}
        \multicolumn{7}{l}{\hskip1.5em\rnode[tl]{P}{Parent chromosomes}}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}%
    \pnode[0.5em,1.2ex]{A} \hspace{2.2cm}\pnode[-0.5em,1.2ex]{W}
    \begin{minipage}{.35\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|*{7}{p{0.3cm}|}}
        \multicolumn{5}{c}{} \\[1.5ex]
            \hline
            \cellcolor{mygrey}D & \cellcolor{mygrey}1 & 0 & 1 & D & 1 & 1 \\
            \hline
        \noalign{\vspace{0.4cm}}
        \hline
     \rowcolor{mygrey}\cellcolor{white} D &\cellcolor{white} 1 & 0 & 1 & D & 1 & 1 \\
        \hline\noalign{\vskip 1.5ex}
        \multicolumn{7}{c}{\hskip1.5em\rnode{O}{offspring chromosomes}}
    \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
    \ncline[arrows=->, arrowinset=0.12, nodesep=2pt, offset =-22pt]{P}{C}
    \psBigArrow[doublesep=3mm](A)(W)
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One more solution with TikZ:

- drawing in the loops
- used libraries `chains`
- conditional coloring of boxes

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, 
                calc, chains,
                fit, 
                positioning,
                shapes.arrows}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 7mm and 0mm,
  start chain = going right,
    ARR/.style = {single arrow, single arrow head extend=2mm, draw,
                  minimum height=5.5em, minimum width=13mm},
    box/.style = {draw, fill=#1, minimum width=1.6em, outer sep=0pt},
    box/.default = cyan!50,
                        ]
\foreach \i [count=\j] in {0,1, 0,1, 0,1, 1}
{
    \node (n1\j) [box,on chain] {\i};
\ifnum\j<3
    \node   [box,right=17em of n1\j] {\i};
\else
    \node   [box=white,right=17em of n1\j] {\i};
\fi
}
\foreach \i [count=\j] in {1,1, 1,0, 0,1, 0}
{
    \node (n2\j) [box=white, below=of n1\j] {\i};
\ifnum\j<3
    \node   [box=white,right=17em of n2\j] {\i};
\else
    \node (n4\j) [box,right=17em of n2\j] {\i};
\fi
}
%
\draw[-Straight Barb, very thick]   ([yshift=-3mm] n22.south east) 
    node (aux1) [align=center, below] {Parent\\ chromosomes} -- 
                        ([yshift=+3mm] n12.north east)
    node (aux2) [align=center, above] {crossover\\ point};
\node[align=center, below] at  (aux1.north -| n44) {offsping\\ chromosomes};
%
\node [ARR,right=1em] at ($(n17.east)!0.5!(n27.east)$)  {};
%
\node [draw, rounded corners, fit = (aux1) (aux2) (n47),
       label={[anchor=north]north: One Point Crossover}] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With some TikZ matrices:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, fit}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{
    mymatr/.style={
        matrix of nodes, 
        inner sep=0pt,
        draw, very thick, 
        nodes={
            draw, very thin,
            minimum size=18pt,
            }
        },
    descr/.style={
        font=\bfseries, 
        inner xsep=0pt
        }
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}            
    \matrix[mymatr, nodes={fill=cyan!50}] (matrA) {0&1& 0&1& 0&1& 1\\};
    \matrix[mymatr,below =.5cm of matrA] (matrB) {1&1& 1&0& 0&1& 0\\};
    \matrix[mymatr,right =2.5cm of matrA] (matrC) 
      {|[fill=cyan!50]|0&|[fill=cyan!50]|1& 1&0& 0&1&0\\};
    \matrix[mymatr,below =.5cm of matrC] (matrD) 
      {1&1&|[fill=cyan!50]| 0&|[fill=cyan!50]|1&
        |[fill=cyan!50]|0&|[fill=cyan!50]|1&|[fill=cyan!50]| 1\\}; 
    \coordinate (AB) at ($(matrA.south east)!.5!(matrB.north east)$);
    \coordinate (CD) at ($(matrC.south west)!.5!(matrD.north west)$);
    \coordinate (ABCD) at ($(AB)!.5!(CD)$);
    \node[draw, single arrow,  minimum height=2cm, minimum width=1.2cm,
      single arrow head extend=3pt,
      single arrow tip angle=100] (myar) at (ABCD) {};
    \draw[-Triangle, very thick,
      shorten >=-10pt,
      shorten <=-10pt]
      (matrB-1-2.south east) -- (matrA-1-2.north east);
    \node[above=10pt, descr, anchor=south west] at (matrA-1-1.north east) 
      {Crossover point};
    \node[below=10pt, descr, anchor=north west] at (matrB-1-1.south east) 
      {Parent chomosomes};
    \node[below=10pt, descr, anchor=north west] (myd) at (matrD-1-1.south) 
      {offspring chomosomes};
    \node[above=40pt of myar, descr] (title) {One point Crossover};
    \node[draw, densely dotted, very thick, fit=(matrA)(title)(myd)(matrD), 
      rounded corners, inner sep=6pt]{};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{My figure caption.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]